# display only if has group of numbers

Tags: php, sql

I need to return list with prices only if there have groups i try already if else empty not !=

nothing help any suggestions ?

```
    $usergroups = '11,9,10';
    if (empty($usergroups)) {
        return;
    }

    $fields = 'MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount = 0, prices.price, prices.price - (prices.price * prices.percentage_discount)/100)) as price, prices.usergroup_id as usergroup_id, ud.usergroup as usergroup_name';

    $condition = db_quote(' prices.product_id = ?i AND prices.usergroup_id IN (?p) AND ud.lang_code = ?s', $product['product_id'], $usergroups, DESCR_SL);

    $group_by = 'usergroup_id';

    $join = '?:usergroup_descriptions as ud ON ud.usergroup_id = prices.usergroup_id';

    $opt_prices = db_get_array("SELECT ?p FROM ?:product_prices as prices LEFT JOIN ?p WHERE ?p GROUP BY ?p", $fields, $join, $condition, $group_by);

    $currencies = Registry::get('currencies');
    foreach ($opt_prices as &$price) {
        $price['current'] = 0;
        if (in_array($price['usergroup_id'], $auth['usergroup_ids'])) {
            $price['current'] = 1;
            $product['price'] = $price['price'];
        }
        $price['price'] = number_format($price['price'], 2, '.', ' ') . ' $';
    }
    $product['group_discounts'] = $opt_prices;    
}
```

So i want display `$product['group_discounts'] = $opt_prices;`
only if there is `$usergroups = '11,9,10';`

Comment: why don't use `in_array` ?

Comment: can you give  example?

Answer (score 0):

Answer your comment:
You used that but ok here an example :

```
<?php

$usergroups = array('11','9','10');
$opt_prices='11';

if (in_array($opt_prices,$usergroups)){
 echo 'yes';   
}else{
 echo 'no';   
}
?>
```

Comment: I think i saw today you Vanila-callendar on githab is your ?

Comment: No no wasn't me.

Comment: okay sorry then . i try what you said it seems not working

Comment: i will try now cause is make server error if i give as array('11,9,10')

Comment: $usergroups = array('11','9','10');
$opt_prices='11'; i have to check 3 of them

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: that code will check if usergroups have value in opt_prices, if you have 3 value to check do three variable opt_prices and 3 or just one if with OR.

Comment: Can you upvote and acept the question if solve your problem?